# SQL: select all the rows from the two userid's with great number of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to get all the rows from the two users with the greatest number of rows, that is, the two users with the greatest activity in a log table.

I have only found next solution: first, get the number of rows for every user, an limit it to 2:

```
SELECT userid, count(*) AS n_of_rows FROM my_table GROUP BY userid LIMIT 2;
```

Then, from the source code I'm querying the database (Python for example), query the database to get the rows of each user:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table where userid = $userid
```

Is it the best/elegant solution, taking into account SQL language itself and database performance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking for is something like

```
select * from my_table where userid in
(select userid from my_table
 group by userid
 order by count(*) desc
 limit 2)
```

Comment: Will this query keep the order of the nested query? I mean, the result will contain first all the rows from the user with the greatest number of rows, and then from the second one?

Comment: You can certainly add `order by userid` after the last parenthesis. When I tested, it did preserve that order, but then I tested the equivalent query in SQL Server, since I don't have mySQL handy.

Comment: I don't want to do a "order by user" in the main select, but an order by the user with the greatest number of rows DESC. Will this order be kept in the main query as it is in the nested one?

Comment: Oh, right.  As I say, when I tested in SQL Server, the rows came out in the order that the userids were in (that is, in the order of the user with the greatest number of rows). But you should test in mySQL.

Comment: I've just tested it in MySQL and the order is not kept. The rows keep the order of the rows in the table, so the first set of rows don't belong to the user who has more rows, but to the first user in the table. So in principle, this solution is not ok for me. Are there any other solution besides the one I provided?

Comment: Yeah, doesn't look like you can do this with a subquery -- Gordon's approach with a join is good.

Answer (score 2):

To get the rows and keep the order, use a `join` with aggregation:

```
select t.*
from my_table t join
     (select userid, count(*) as cnt
      from my_table
      group by userid
      order by count(*) desc
      limit 2
     ) top2
     on t.userid = top2.userid
order by top2.cnt desc, userid;
```

Comment: I've just tested it in MySQL but doesn't work. Nested query returns userid's in the right order, but the final result returns rows taking into account the order in the table, not from the greatest number of rows to the lowest. I mean, first row is for userid 1, but userid 2 is the one with the greatest number of rows, but it seems that, as userid 1 appears first, the whole query return first the rows for userid 1, then for userid 2.

Comment: @David . . . The reason it "didn't work" is because the `order by` was sorting in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 2 userid, count(*) AS n_of_rows 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY userid 
ORDER BY count(*) desc
```

Comment: `SELECT TOP 2` is a SQL Server syntax -- the question is about MySQL.